# получаю NotFoundException при запуске integrationTest

Tags: java, spring, junit

Пробую написать интеграционый тест слоя сервиса. И на первом же методе сохранения данных в БД получаю ошибку.
Записываю объект User в БД и в этом же методе пробую его прочитать и в ответ получаю пустой объект.

Класс сущности

```
@Getter@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class UserEntity {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private I id;
    
    private String name;
}
```

Сервис

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserEntity create(UserEntity object) {
        return UserRepository.save(object);
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntity get(Long id) {
        return UserRepository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(USER_NOT_FOUND));        
    }        
}
```

Для тестов использую БД h2, настройки стандартные

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: password
```

Итерационые тесты для слоя сервиса

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class UserIntTest {
  
    @Autowired
    private UserService UserService;
 
    @Test
    public void saveUser_shouldOK() {
        var result = userService.create(User_02);

        var user = userService.get(2L);

        assertThat(result, notNullValue());
        assertThat(result.getId(), is(1L));
    }
}
```

Сохраняю пользователя в БД и при чтении получаю NotFoundException.
Почему я не могу прочитать данные из БД?
И как это исправить?

Comment: попробуйте `var user = userService.get(result.getId());`

Comment: Так сработало. Получается, что если я при записи указываю конкретный id jpa все равно установит свой.
Можете оформить в виде ответа. И я закрою вопрос.

Comment: Немного не так. Есть разные режимы формирования primary key и у вас установлен `GenerationType.IDENTITY` - айдишник генерируется базой. т.е. пока вы свою сущность не сохраните, её id неизвестно.